# Create a dashboard using different report and overlay element

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have create two different report from two differente data source (on from sql connection and one from analtys services). Now i need create a dashboard and need to overlay element from report sql server with element from analysis service but i cant'

There are any system to do that? I need put "media mese" inside blank space under row "linea 2505"

Using app powerbi

[image]

Thanks